# Merge Pandas dataframes if string df2.domain occurs within df.url

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes: df

```
ID   url
111   vk.com/audio/12353546
222   twitter.com/lenad
333   avito.ru/phones
333   facebook.ru/chats
```

and another df2

```
domain   Maincategory   Subcategory
vk.com    Entertainment   Social Network
twitter.com    Entertainment   Social Network
facebook.com   Entertainment   Social Network
avito.com     Online shop      Buys
vk.com/audio    Entertainment   Social Network Music
```

I need to do the followimg:
if some string from `df2.domain.values.tolist()` occurs in `df.url`, add the columns of `df` from `df2` (`Maincategory` and `Subcategory`) and get:

```
ID   url    Maincategory    Subcategory
111   vk.com/audio/12353546    Entertainment   Social Network Music
222   twitter.com/lenad    Entertainment   Social Network
333   avito.ru/phones    Online shop      Buys
333   facebook.ru/chats    Entertainment   Social Network
```

I have some way to do it, but it takes too many time.

```
mapping = dict(df2.set_index('domain')['Maincategory'])
def map_to_substring(x):
    for key in mapping.keys():
        if key in x:
            return mapping[key]
    return 'None'

df['Maincategory'] = df.url.apply(lambda x: map_to_substring(x))

mapping1 = dict(df2.set_index('domain')['Subcategory'])
def map_to_substring1(x):
    for key in mapping1.keys():
        if key in x:
            return mapping1[key]
    return 'None'

df['Subcategory'] = df.url.apply(lambda x: map_to_substring1(x))
```

How can I improve that?

Comment: "Add the columns of df2 if `df2.domain` column occurs inside `df1.url`" is called **merging the two dataframes**, on a specific condition. Your case is a little more complicated, as the `merge` operation is not just testing that two (id) columns are equal, which is usually what a merge does.

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is that you want to get the id from df and place it on df2?

there are many ways you can do that. you can merge the df:

```
pd.merge(df2,df, on='url')
```

that however can lead to issues if you have duplicated values on 'url'

you can also map

```
df2['id'] = df2['url'].map(lambda x: df.loc[df['url']==x, 'ID'].iloc[0])
```

hope that helps, peace

Comment: If you check the urls in df1 and df2, You will see, that there are not equal and I can lose a lot of data

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['111', '222', '333', '333'],'url':['vk.com/audio/12353546','twitter.com/lenad','avito.ru/phones','facebook.ru/chats']})
print "----original df1----"
print df1
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                'Maincaregory':['Entertainment','Entertainment','Entertainment','Online shop','Entertainment'],
                'Subcategory':['Social Network','Social Network','Social Network','Buys','Social Network Music'],
               'domain':  ['vk.com','twitter.com','facebook.com','avito.com','vk.com/audio']})
print "\n----original df2----"                    
print df2
row = df1.shape[0]
dname =[]
for x in range(row):
    name = df1.iloc[x]['url'].split(".")
    if name[0] == 'vk':
        cat = df1.iloc[x]['url'].split("/")
        dname.append(cat[0]+"/"+cat[1])
    else:
        dname.append(name[0]+".com")

df1['domain']=dname
print "\n----for merge df1----"
print df1

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner',on=['domain'])
df3= df3.drop('domain',1)
print "\n----what you want----"
print df3
```

result:

```
----original df1----
    ID                    url
0  111  vk.com/audio/12353546
1  222      twitter.com/lenad
2  333        avito.ru/phones
3  333      facebook.ru/chats

----original df2----
    Maincaregory           Subcategory        domain
0  Entertainment        Social Network        vk.com
1  Entertainment        Social Network   twitter.com
2  Entertainment        Social Network  facebook.com
3    Online shop                  Buys     avito.com
4  Entertainment  Social Network Music  vk.com/audio

----for merge df1----
    ID                    url        domain
0  111  vk.com/audio/12353546  vk.com/audio
1  222      twitter.com/lenad   twitter.com
2  333        avito.ru/phones     avito.com
3  333      facebook.ru/chats  facebook.com

----what you want----
    ID                    url   Maincaregory           Subcategory
0  111  vk.com/audio/12353546  Entertainment  Social Network Music
1  222      twitter.com/lenad  Entertainment        Social Network
2  333        avito.ru/phones    Online shop                  Buys
3  333      facebook.ru/chats  Entertainment        Social Network
```

Comment: `vk.com/audio` has a Subcategory `Social Network Music`

Comment: I didn't get what I want. If it compare domains, it doesn't return correct category

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what's different.@@

Comment: oh, I see. there are vk.com and vk.com/audio